# Django Rest Framework JWT authentication asking for CSRF token

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I am using django rest framework simplejwt for authentication. Here is the rest framework settings:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES' : [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES' : [
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication'
    ],
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS' : 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE' : 3
}
```

As much as I am aware, if no DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES are mention, django will default to the session based authentication which requires csrf token. I have not included the session authentication and have used simplejwt as shown above. Yet I receive the error of CSRF verification failed when handling POST requests, which is not supposed to be required. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

Did you try this:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES' : [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES' : [
        'rest_framework.rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication'
    ],
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS' : 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE' : 3
}
```

Comment: Just tried this. It gives an error. So no, this is an invalid method